# How to pass reusable form data in angular?

Tags: angular

I'm using a reactive form in a an angular 9.
I would like to have reusable forms. because of that I created a separated component for forms.
but I don't know how I can pass the form values to another components **without any click in form component**, because I want to have separate button for each components.
How I can write the send function in app.component?

**form.component.html**

```
 <form [formGroup]="form">
      <div *ngFor="let prop of personProps">
        <label>{{ prop.label }}:</label>

        <div [ngSwitch]="prop.type">
          <input *ngSwitchCase="'text'" [type]="prop.type" [formControlName]="prop.key">
          <input *ngSwitchCase="'number'" [type]="prop.type" [formControlName]="prop.key">
        </div>

      </div>
    </form>
```

**app.component.html**

```
<dynamic-form [formDataObj]="person"></dynamic-form>
<button (click)="send()"> click </button>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

just use a template reference variable (the #nameVariable)

```
<dynamic-form #myform [formDataObj]="person"></dynamic-form>
<button (click)="send(myform)"> click </button>
```

in function send you has all the public properties of the dynamicform, e.g. the own variable "form"

```
send(myform:any)
{
    if (myform.form.valid)
       console.log(myform.form.value)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

have function inside your dynamic-form like this to initialize the form variables

```
@Input() formData;
buildForm() {
    this.myForm = this.fb.group({
     ...
    });
  }
```

trigger the build form on the ngOnInit and ngOnchanges

```
ngOnInit() {
    this.buildForm();
  }

ngOnChanges(changes: SimpleChanges) {
        if (changes.formData && !changes.formData.firstChange){
            this.buildForm();
        }
}
```

Now in your App component

```
send() {
this. person = // your code here
}
```